# Java: storing a big map in resources

Tags: java, dictionary, serialization

I need to use a big file that contains String,String pairs and because I want to ship it with a JAR, I opted to include a serialized and gzipped version in the resource folder of the application. This is how I created the serialization:

```
ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(
            new BufferedOutputStream(new GZIPOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(OUT_FILE_PATH, false))));
out.writeObject(map);
out.close();
```

I chose to use a `HashMap<String,String>`, the resulting file is 60MB and the map contains about 4 million entries.

Now when I need the map and I deserialize it using:

```
final InputStream in = FileUtils.getResource("map.ser.gz");
final ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(new GZIPInputStream(in)));
map = (Map<String, String>) ois.readObject();
ois.close();
```

this takes about 10~15 seconds. Is there a better way to store such a big map in a JAR? I ask because I also use the Stanford CoreNLP library which uses big model files itself but seems to perform better in that regard. I tried to locate the code where the model files are read but gave up.

Comment: What takes 10~15 seconds? Writing or reading the map? What do you want to improve?

Comment: His second code explicitly tells it takes 10-15sec to read the file

Comment: check this to increase serialization performance and see flush method. http://www.drdobbs.com/jvm/increase-java-serialization-performance/240159166

Comment: Some benchmarks here, maybe it could help : 
http://nadeausoftware.com/articles/2008/02/java_tip_how_read_files_quickly#Conclusions

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is you zipped the data. Store it plain text.

The performance hit is most probably in unzipping the stream. Jars are *already* zipped, so there's no space saving storing the file zipped.

Basically:

- Store the file in plain text
- Use `Files.lines(Paths.get("myfilenane.txt"))` to stream the lines
- Consume each line with minimal code

Something like this, assuming data is in form `key=value` (like a Properties file):

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
Files.lines(Paths.get("myfilenane.txt"))
  .map(s -> s.split("="))
  .forEach(a -> map.put(a[0], a[1]));
```

<sub>Disclaimer: Code may not compile or work as it was thumbed in on my phone (but there's a reasonable chance it will work)</sub>

Comment: Multiple issues with this one. Its not a file on the file system, but a resource inside my JAR, but line reading is no problem. Using streams and splitting every line separately actually makes this slower than the deserialization.

Comment: @eike I know it's in the jar. That's the point - it's *already* zipped when it's added to the jar. OK, I misread your question (the file is a serialised object, not a text file), but the basics of my answer still apply: Don't zip the file - put it in the jar as-is.

Comment: Yes, not zipping it makes it faster

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to apply a technique coming from the book **Java Performance: The definitive guide** from **Scott Oaks** which actually stores the zipped content of the object into a byte array so for this we need a wrapper class that I call here `MapHolder`:

```
public class MapHolder implements Serializable {
    // This will contain the zipped content of my map
    private byte[] content;
    // My actual map defined as transient as I don't want to serialize its 
    // content but its zipped content
    private transient Map<String, String> map;

    public MapHolder(Map<String, String> map) {
        this.map = map;
    }

    private void writeObject(ObjectOutputStream out) throws IOException {
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        try (GZIPOutputStream zip = new GZIPOutputStream(baos);
            ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(
                new BufferedOutputStream(zip))) {
            oos.writeObject(map);
        }
        this.content = baos.toByteArray();
        out.defaultWriteObject();
        // Clear the temporary field content
        this.content = null;
    }

    private void readObject(ObjectInputStream in) throws IOException,
        ClassNotFoundException {
        in.defaultReadObject();
        try (ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(content);
            GZIPInputStream zip = new GZIPInputStream(bais);
            ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(
                new BufferedInputStream(zip))) {
            this.map = (Map<String, String>) ois.readObject();
            // Clean the temporary field content
            this.content = null;
        }
    }

    public Map<String, String> getMap() {
        return this.map;
    }
}
```

Your code will then simply be:

```
final ByteArrayInputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(
    Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("/tmp/map.ser"))
);
final ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(in);
MapHolder holder = (MapHolder) ois.readObject();
map = holder.getMap();
ois.close();
```

As you may have noticed, you don't zip anymore the content it is zipped internally while serializing the `MapHolder` instance.

Comment: `FileUtils.getResource("map.ser.gz")` returns an InputStream of the file contained in the resources folder inside the JAR. I used your solution and see a minimal speedup

Answer (score 0):

You could consider one of many fast serialization libraries:

- protobuf (https://github.com/google/protobuf)
- flat buffers (https://google.github.io/flatbuffers/)
- cap'n proto (https://capnproto.org)